# There do not exist sets that are elements of each other

Tags: set-theory

Prove that there do not exist sets $X$ and $Y$ such that $X\in Y$ and $Y\in X$.

I have no idea how to do this, and I could use some help

Comment: Among the axioms you have learned for set theory, is there one called something like "regularity" or "foundation"? If so, please state it as it appears in your book, as that is what we have to use to answer your question.

Comment: @bof Yes!It says:  if X is a non-empty set then there is an $A\in X$ such that $A \cap X = \emptyset$

Comment: I see how I can reach a contradiction from that. If $M$ is in $\{A,B\}$ then their intersection is empty and since it only has those two elements then $M$ is either $A$ or $B$ and since they are both elements this is a contradiction

Comment: How exactly is this contradiction related to the original question. That's really my issue

Comment: I understand that. I am just not sure how assuming that $\{A,B\}$ is a set is related to the original phrasing of the question

Comment: $\{A,B\}$ is a set by the axiom of pairs. No issue there. But it's not regular so it contradicts another axiom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume we have sets $X,Y$ such that $X\in Y$ and $Y\in X.$ Let $W=\{X,Y\}.$ By the axiom of regularity, there is a set $A\in W$ such that $A\cap W=\emptyset.$ So $A=X$ or $A=Y.$ But if $A=X$ then $A\cap W\ne\emptyset$ since $Y\in X\cap W=A\cap W.$ Likewise $A=Y$ is impossible. We arrive at a contradiction, proving that there are no such sets $X$ and $Y.$